# Are there any APIs that allow job candidates to programmatically submit applications?

Tags: linkedin-api

See ^. I'm looking for an API that provides three main options:

Searching for jobs by topics (i.e ML, software engineering, etc.)

Get specific questions for the job (to answer, I'll answer using GPT-4 + LangChain).

Submitting the application to the endpoint.

Is there some sort of job platform that exposes an API that does ALL three, particularly #3? I've seen a lot of "Job Search" APIs that tackle #1, but nothing that answers #2 or #3.

Basically, I'm trying to automate the process of my job applications, and need an API (okay if paid) that I can perform complete interactions with.

LinkedIn -- appears to have job search only
Indeed   -- appears to have job search only
Angelist/Wellfound -- appears to have job search only